# Can't redirect from Web User Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have AppLogin.ascx in /WebControls/Login folder and want to redirect to a page /Users/Login.aspx and it will not redirect and sends me to my localhost. My web user control is used in ApplicationLogin.aspx in the /Users folder.

```
 If redirect Then
        Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("Login.aspx")
        Response.Redirect(path)
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Server.MapPath, which actually maps the page to physical directory of the page.Just use

```
Response.Redirect("~/Users/Login.aspx")
```

Comment: deleting my answer, the `~` is correct... no clue why I put in the `.`.